# Bash shell command doesn't work without echo

Tags: shell, mv

Total beginner here, trying to write some code to remove first space from a batch of file names.

When I type in terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.jpg; do echo mv "$f" “${f/ /}”; done
```

I get:

```
mv R 1  Pe.jpg “R1 Pe.jpg”
mv R 10 Ma.jpg “R10 Ma.jpg”
mv R 11 An.jpg “R11 An.jpg”
```

But when I remove echo, the actual renaming does not happen, I get this error:

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" “${f/ /}”; done
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note there is no limit to the number of characters after the `.`, therefore you can name your files `*.jpeg`. Not even Microsoft's OSes have this limit: not since 1995.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't quotes. You have `“` not `"`:

```
$ uniprops “
U+201C ‹“› \N{LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK}
    \pP \p{Pi}
    All Any Assigned Punct Is_Punctuation Common Zyyy Pi P General_Punctuation
       InPunctuation Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph GrBase
       Initial_Punctuation Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn Print X_POSIX_Print
       Punctuation QMark Quotation_Mark Unicode X_POSIX_Punct


$ uniprops '"'
U+0022 ‹"› \N{QUOTATION MARK}
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Basic_Latin Punct Is_Punctuation Common Zyyy Po P
       Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation
       Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn POSIX_Graph POSIX_Print POSIX_Punct Print
       X_POSIX_Print Punctuation QMark Quotation_Mark Unicode X_POSIX_Punct
```

Since the quotes in the target names are not proper double quotes, the second argument would be split on spaces, and the first  `mv` command would try to move the two files `R 1  Pe.jpg` and `“R1` to non-existing directory `Pe.jpg”`. This is what causes the errors.

So try this:

```
for f in *.jpg; do echo mv "$f" "${f/ /}"; done
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks for pointing out the obvious mistake. Noted the difference between ASCI and Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a quoting problem (see other answers).

However for this specific problem, it is better done with the `rename` command.
(The one by Larry Wall)

e.g.

```
rename -n -e "s/ //" *.jpg
```

After testing, and checking the output. Remove the `-n`.

## Installing

On Debian with `apt install rename`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the quotes are an issue. The echo shows the command as:
`mv R 1  Pe.jpg “R1 Pe.jpg”` 
If you were to type this onto the command line, it would fail, because the spaces in the source are neither quoted nor escaped. The correct command would be: 
`mv "R 1  Pe.jpg" "R1 Pe.jpg"` 
To put quites around the $f variable, I would suggest something like this: 
`mv "\""$f"\""  "${f/ /}"` 
where the "\"" is the escape code to print a double quote. 
To wit: `echo " n "`  displays `n`. echo " \n " escapes the n and shows a newline. Similarly, `echo " \" "` escapes a quote inside quotes. 
Another option qould be: 
`mv '"'$f'"' "${f/ /}"`

Comment: Why would you add two layers of quotes around `$f`? And `echo "\n"` won't print a newline in any echo implementation I know of. Some would with `echo -e "\n"`. The OP's command was fine, they just weren't using ASCI quotes but instead had fancy unicode.

Comment: Disagree. The first argument of the mv command contains spaces. It will not work as intended. the first arg should be EITHER: "R 1  Pe.jpg" -or- R\ 1\ Pe.jpg.  Otherwise, the mv command has 4 arguments: Arg1 `R` arg2 `1` arg3 `Pe.jpg` arg4 `R1\ Pe.jpg`

Comment: @terndon It is also possible that the Unicode quotes were simple a translation issue from the original source into the test window. Is it even possible you to easily put Unicode quotes into your script while using a text editor?

Comment: @terndon, I have had echo "Line 1\nLine 2" work without the -e. And, don't be dumb, clearly it is just an example for level of understanding.

Comment: The first argument is already `"$f"`, look at the code. The problem is when the command is run in the script, not when it is echoed. If you want the quotes to appear in the output of echo, then you can do `echo mv "\"$f\""` but not when running the command. And you never need the over complicated quoting you showed. Just `echo mv "\"$f\""`, no need for `echo mv "\""$f"\""`. Yes, it is possible to get unicode quotes easily, it isn't the first time we have seen questions like this. And we know the quotes are the issue because he code is otherwise fine, and the command would have worked.

Comment: If you have had `echo Line 1\nLine 2"` work, then you probably have `echo` aliased to `echo -n`. Or are using a very unusual implementation of `echo`. It certainly isn't standard. Finally, we expect all users to be polite with each other here. Don't go around calling others dumb.

Comment: @terdon, dash and zsh process backslashes in echo by default. And well, [the standard leaves it implementation defined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: @ilkkachu ah, thanks. I didn't know about dash and zsh doing that. But since this question is about bash, that doesn't really make much difference.

Comment: @terndon: You said: `echo mv "\"$f\""` Which was exactly my point. Thank you for re-iterating it.  Why the 'overly cpmplicateds' "\""? Because other folks will be reading this in the future and SOMETIMES it is required to add a double quote inside a double quote. Remember that other people, other than the OP will be reading these later to solve their problems. Now they have multiple ways to insert quotes -- all stored in one question. *High Five*